# Borland C++ 5.0 Makefile generation

Tags: makefile, borland-c++

I am using Borland C++ 3.1 and Borland C++ 5.0a to compile my projects. To speed up the process I decided to use a batch file to make all the projects with make utilities. There is a way to convert BC3 .prj files to .mak file with PRJ2MAK.exe, but, as far as I know, in BC5 projects it should be done through manual pressing of "Project -> Generate makefile" buttons in IDE. Is there any way to convert .ide files to .mak files in CMD?

Answer (score 1):

In BC5 bin folder there should be an "idetomak" utility. At least BC5.02 has it.

Note that for some complex projects the generated .mak file may not be fully compatible. In that case you may instead run BC5 ide from the command line, telling it to build the .ide project

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I'll look into BC5.02 version for the .exe. And I even stumbled onto complex project with incompatible .mak already, so I'll try your suggestion as soon as I am able.

Comment: The commands are: "bcw -b project_filename" to build the project and "bcw -m project_filename" to make the project. After the compilation is finished, the ide will close.

Comment: Also, if by chance your applications use OWL (Object Windows Library). are you aware of the OWLNext project (https://sourceforge.net/projects/owlnext/), that ports the library to modern compilers like Visual C++?